# How to prevent \section from starting on a new page in the scrartcl class?

Tags: sectioning

I browsed through the question history for a while but could not find something helpful for my problem. Sorry, in case I missed a fitting case.

I use document class `scrartcl` for writing my PhD thesis. I want my sections to start directly after the previous text ended, i.e. I want to prevent them from starting automatically on a new page. How do I do this?

Alternatively, is there another document class that you would recommend?

I am still at beginner level of LaTeX, so I would appreciate a simple solution ;)

---

UPDATE:

Wow. Thx for the quick responses! And yes, I do use \include. Sorry, I was not aware that this can cause "special effects"...So, can I do something to prevent this from happening?

@egreg: Thx. I will give the "scrbook" a shot. Although, it will not solve my \inlcude-problem, I guess?

@wasteofspace: No, I am not using \chapter as "section".

---

UPDATE2:

@Joseph: Because I am new to this and have not known better. I got a template from a collegue and this was its documentclass. I will try the one recommended by egreg.

Comment: What you describe is not the standard behaivour, sections usually starts directly after each other. Could it be that you use `\include{}` or something similar?

Could you post a MWE with your problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By default, `\section` doesn't make LaTeX start a new page. If this happens to you, then you must have something that causes it in your document preamble. Or usage of `\include`, of course. I'm not sure that `scrartcl` is good for a PhD thesis, probably `scrbook` is better.

Comment: are you using `\chapter` for your "sections"?

Comment: Use `\input` instead of `\include`

Comment: I second egreg's comment: Why are you using an article class for a thesis?

Comment: Addendum to @egreg Or use `scrreprt`. You can see the names somehow refer to the type of document you are going to write. A PhD-Thesis is most certainly longer than just a few pages. With `scrreprt` and `scrbook` you also got chapters.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)